# How to get certain last characets delimited by certain character?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, text-formatting

I have a file , when i type this command i get this

```bsh
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# cat hi | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | awk -F '://' '{print $2}' 
127.0.0.1:80/bWAPP
127.0.0.1:80/admin
127.0.0.1:80/admin/200
127.0.0.1:80/admin/200/400/500/6000/7000
```

So, i wanted to extract last part of every line , it could be done with cut but its not what i want, like if i do

```bsh
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# cat hi | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | awk -F '://' '{print $2}'  | cut -d '/' -f 2
bWAPP
admin
admin
admin
```

i get admin and bWAPP. However i wanted to get bWAPP , admin, 200, 7000. How could i extract `/lastpart` of the line.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include sample input (i.e. the input of the file `hi`) - this will enable contributors to point you to better solutions, cascaded `awk` calls as shown in your question are seldom necessary ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `sed` :

```
sed 's|.*/||' hi
```

Comment: Hmm regex looks weird, but works

Comment: cool. This matches until your delimiter and exclude it while printing.

Comment: Actually you don't even need a match group in this case. Simple `sed 's|.*/||' hi` will suffice.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt : yeah , right , thats what i thought first and somehow i confused with `d` command, i ended with this one. Thanks for reminding me again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the last `/`-delimited field of each line, you can use `/` as field separator and access the last field directly:

```
awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: GOOD THANKS AWESOME

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily. Still, I think your original command can be made more efficient by combining both `awk` calls into one; if you would post the content of this `hi` file, we might be able to help you there, too.